# Stack trace printing to System.out but not System.err

Tags: java, printstacktrace

I'm using this class(JSch) that I don't understand completely, but I have a rough idea on how it works. I'm trying to throw an Exception if the exitStatus is not what I want. However, using

```
e.printStackTrace() or e.printStackTrace(System.err) //does nothing

e.printStackTrace(System.out) //prints the whole stack trace.
```

I've never seen this problem before, so I was wondering if it's the API that I'm not understanding that is causing the problem or does the Exception stack trace work differently? I have a feeling that using apache log4j would work, but I'm too lazy to set it up just for testing purpose, and it would not answer the confusion on why this is happening.

If interested, here is the code (I want to throw an Exception when exitStatus != 0):

```
    Channel channel = null;
    int exitStatus = 1;
    System.out.println(command);
    try {
        channel = session.openChannel("exec");
        ChannelExec channelExec = (ChannelExec) channel;
        channelExec.setPty(true);
        channelExec.setCommand(command);
        channelExec.setInputStream(null);
        channelExec.setErrStream(System.err);
        InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
        channel.connect();

        byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
        int timeout = 0;
        while (true){
            while (in.available() > 0) {
                timeout = 0; // if read success, reset timeout
                int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if (i < 0)break;
                String status = new String(tmp, 0, i);
                /*System.out.println(status);*/
                if (status.toLowerCase().contains("incorrect password")) {
                    channel.disconnect();
                } else if (status.toLowerCase().contains("password")) {
                    OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
                    out.write(args);
                    out.write('\n');
                    out.close();
                }
            }
            if (channel.isClosed()){
                exitStatus = channel.getExitStatus();
                break;
            }
            try { Thread.sleep(1000); } catch (Exception ee) { ee.printStackTrace(); }
            // nothing reads for 4 turns but stream is not closing, probably waiting for user input so exit
            if (timeout++ > 5) { 
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new ApplicationException(ioe);
    } catch (JSchException je) { 
        throw new ApplicationException("Could not create an exec channel for SSH. ", je);
    } finally {
        if (channel.isConnected()) channel.disconnect();
    }

  //if (exitStatus != 0) throw new MyCustomException(errormsg)
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are asking why `//if (exitStatus != 0)` does not work?  it is commented out.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Where are you trying to print the stack trace? And if you want to throw an exception when exitStatus is not 0, what is preventing you from doing so?

Comment: Does _anything_ you print to System.err appear? Maybe you've redirected stderr to a file or to /dev/null.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Thanks, your comment gives me a hint to my problem. The problem is this line of code at line 10:

        `channelExec.setErrStream(System.err);`